# creating string arrays through for loop, in java

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have a long Array, and for every long value i m using this query to fetch a string Array from sqlite database.

```
long[] mylong= {1,3,5,6,7};
Dbadapter finaldb = new Dbadapter(this);
for(int i=0; i<mylong.length; i++) {
        finaldb.open();
        String[] string_array = finaldb.getArray(mylong[i]);
        finaldb.close();
```

now, i want to store these different string arrays with some name so that i can use them after. but i don't know how to achieve this. If any one can guide me in the right direction?

Comment: `java.util.Map<Long, String[]>`

Comment: You can store them in a List<String[]> (to access by index) or Map<String,String[]> (to access by a String key)

Comment: create a class that contains a long variable and a String array. Use this object collection to store the result.

Comment: @dasrohith can you elaborate?

Comment: not getting the reason behind too many down votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have [`ArrayList<String[]>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) to store arrays and add those array to list and use get method to retrieve the array or you can use [`Map<key,value>`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_map_interface.htm) to manage the key value based structure for retrieval of array.

***FOR EXAMPLE***

```
String str[]=new String[10];
str[0]="abc";
//and other values
List<String[]> list=new ArrayList<String[]>();
list.add(str);
//OR
Map<Long,String[]> map=new HashMap<Long,String[]>();
map.put(myLong[0],str);
```

Comment: Can you please give an example, that how can i use this to store arrays using for loop?

Comment: Are you sure about your first solution that it will store different string arrays?

Comment: It will store `String` _arrays_.

Comment: Ok, so what if we have to access the items of second or third String array?

Comment: `list.get(2)[0]` and `list.get(3)[0]` 0 stands for array index

Comment: if i want to compare the second string array to a string value to see if array contain a certain item, how would i do that? like i m doing it like this,  list.get(1).contains("abc") ,, but m getting error on this.

Comment: @Hayasuleman `list.get(1)` returns array and you can't call contain method on that and if you want to use contain you have to convert it to list. `Arrays.asList(list.get(1)).contains("abc")`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that contains a long variable and a String array. Use this object collection to store the result.

See code snippet below

```
Class Result{
private long key;
private String[] value;


public Result(long key, String[] value){
this.key = key;
this value = value;
}

//getter setter goes here
}
```

modified code below

```
long[] mylong= {1,3,5,6,7};
List<Result> result = new ArrayList<Result>();
Dbadapter finaldb = new Dbadapter(this);
for(int i=0; i<mylong.length; i++) {
        finaldb.open();
        String[] string_array = finaldb.getArray(mylong[i]);
        result.add(new Result(mylong[i]),string_array ));
        finaldb.close();
```

You can use the  List for further operations

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I really understand what you want to do, but it seems like you want to store the String[] db results in a Map using a String name.

Below I give an example how to do that. You can easily put this in a loop if you understand the concept. Hopefully this makes sense. I tried to match what you might actually be using.

```
String[] names = {"one", "two", "three", "four"};
String[] string_array = {"1.0", "2.1", "7.9"};
Map<String,String[]> storage = new HashMap<String,String[]>();

storage.put(names[0], string_array);
```